# How do functions and lists work together?

Tags: python

when I am trying to append a list, it's working weirdly. Suppose this is my code:

```
a = [1]
b = a
c = a

def func(a):
    a.append([50])
```

Here is the output:

```
a
[1]    
b
[1]
c
[1]

func(c)
c
[1,50]  # good till now
```

But now when I try to print a or b, I should get just [1] right? But no, here's what I get:

```
b
[1,50]
```

Please explain...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here 'b' and 'c' have reference of 'a'. Since 'a' is a list and is mutable, any changes to 'a' will also reflect in 'b' and 'c'.

to make a copy of object, use

```
import copy
a=[10]
b= copy.deepcopy(a)
c= copy.deepcopy(a)
```

Now pass 'a', 'b' or 'c' to the function, you will get separate values for each of them

Cheers

Comment: Then how should i declare b such that it gets initialised to a but not change whenever c is changed?

Comment: Check the linked duplicate questions.

Comment: use `b = a[:]` or `b = copy.deepcopy(a)`